# How to correctly set a max-height on Kendo Scheduler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am wondering if anyone has an idea on how to achieve the following behavior with the Kendo Scheduler:

I want the height of the scheduler to be the height of its contents UNTIL it reaches the height of the browser (which I already have calculated), then have that as far as it goes and become scrollable.

Right now, I just set the height to the height of the browser, but this causes views like the timeline views and when showing only business hours (which are all much shorter than other views) to have extra unneeded white space underneath it because the scheduler is still the height of the browser window.

I have kind of achieved this by setting the max-height of my  that I initialize as the scheduler to the browser height. The only issue with this, is that it makes the whole scheduler scrollable (including the header with the date navigation tools, which I don't want). I only want the content under the header to be scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the DOM. You'll notice that the scheduler's content 
gets rendered within a `<table>` separated from the header.

Technically, you could wrap a `<div>` around the widget's table and set it's CSS-property `height` or `max-height` to the desired height and `overflow-y` to `scroll` or `auto`. This way, you could achieve what you want.

Have a look at the following code-snippet. It should do the trick:

```
$("#scheduler > table.k-scheduler-layout").wrap("<div style='max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;'></div>")
```

However, I haven't tested if manipulating the HTML-structure this way will introduce any unexpected side-effects from kendo's side during regular usage of the widget.

UPDATE:
During the rendering-process when navigating to a different view, kendo removes the old `table` in order to render the new one - obviously - using the same routine as before. What remains is the empty `<div>` we created above and the new `table`, both directly underneath the widgets parent-node `$("#scheduler")`. This means that the code from above has to be executed after the grid's data has been bound. You can use the dataBound-event for this purpose. Docs: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#events-dataBound)

The updated code-snippet, showing how the event-method could look like:

```
  function scheduler_DataBound() {
    $("#scheduler > .scheduler-content-wrapper").remove();//Reset the DOM after changing page
    $("#scheduler > table.k-scheduler-layout").wrap("<div class='scheduler-content-wrapper' style='max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;'></div>");
    $("#scheduler .k-scheduler-content").css("overflow-x", "hidden");//Fix horizontal scrollbar
  }
```

UPDATE 2: I found out that the grid will crash in the case the dataBound-event gets fired after resizing the page or opening the editor-popup. My first thought was that `dataBound` isn't the right place to resize the grid. After trying to run the code through the `navigate`-event, which I think should be the right place, I found out that the only way to get it working from there is to surround the code with `setTimeout(function(){ /* code... */ })`. While this works, the delayed rendering looks terrible in the browser. Finally, I changed the code in order to set a flag whenever the grid should be resized after `dataBound`. Of course it feels cheesy to spread around that much code just to resize a widget. But from my current point of understanding this is the only acceptable solution if user experience matters.

```
<script>
  var resizeScheduler = true;
  function scheduler_DataBound() {
    if (!resizeScheduler) {//Prevent grid crash, when event fired on page resize
      return; 
    }

    resizeScheduler = false;
    $("#scheduler > .scheduler-content-wrapper").remove();
    $("#scheduler > table.k-scheduler-layout").wrap("<div class='scheduler-content-wrapper' style='max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;'></div>");
    $("#scheduler .k-scheduler-content").css("overflow-x", "hidden");//Fix horizontal scrollbar
  }
  function scheduler_Navigate() {
    resizeScheduler = true;
  }
</script>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting... I should see if wrapping a div around the table would work. If you don't specify a height for the scheduler, the scheduler grows with its contents, so if a div wrapped it with a max height, and that just worked, that would be much simpler.

Comment: Messing around with it... it works, until you change things by switching between full day and work hours (just using their demo, and modifying things in a dojo). It looks like it needs a resize after changing to work hours, but resize and view refresh aren't behaving as they should in the Dojo, not sure if that is their demo, or this kind of 'hack'.

Comment: @TylerDahle I've tested it on my machine. As you observed correctly, The layout crashes after switching to a different page. I'll update my answer

Comment: I am currently recalculating and re-setting the height anytime the scheduler changes, this does get complicated with the agenda view (because I hide and reveal extra info via a button for the events there) and requires flags to be set and checked. And doing it this way involves multiple resizes and view refreshes... but it may be the only real way. If something as simple as you suggested would work, though, that would be so much simpler.

Comment: @TylerDahle I just updated the answer. Have a look at it and let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thank you for the update. That does work well when navigating views and dates. The only issue is with switching from full day to work hours. I don't think the scheduler refreshes itself when you click show work hours, so it gets a double scroll bar, and if you scroll all the way down, the bottom gets really funky. Unfortunately, if you refresh the view in the scheduler, it randomly loads the whole demo page instead of just refreshing the scheduler view.

Comment: @TylerDahle The horizontal scrollbar you mentioned shows up because of the additional width caused by the vertical scrollbar. Setting the property overflow-x of the css-class k-scheduler-content to hidden should fix the issue. I updated the answer again.